# Does the mastered super saiyan blue exists in the anime?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

So since the battle with Zamasu Dragon Ball Super manga introduced the concept of mastered super saiyan blue, which it would be a stronger version of super saiyan blue, I guess similar to as super saiyan full power is a stronger version of super saiyan. Now they've used again in the last manga chapter,

> making Vegita being able to land a punch on Beerus when using it, and getting Beerus to say may be he could be a god of destruction in another universe, but not in this one.

Then, does this concept of the mastered super saiyan blue exists in the anime? People were arguing before than super saiyan god transformation "at will" from Goku only existed in the manga, but now we've seen super saiyan god transformation will appear again in Dragon Ball Super anime episode 104th. Does this mean mastered Super Saiyan Blue will also exist in the anime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the anime isn't going to have a literal "Mastered SSJB" transformation. I think it's fair to assume that both Goku and Vegeta have mastered it to an extent to which it can be considered as Mastered SSJB. We see them being to efficiently use the transformation without much stamina loss. Also, the SSJB transformation is mainly about ki control and we see goku efficiently utilising this while even fighting someone as weak as Krillin. In the tournament of power, we see goku being able to use Kaioken+SSJB a lot more easily without it having any effect on his body now compared to the Universe 6 vs 7 tournament arc. So I think it is fair to assume that at least goku has mastered it. If Goku had to reach the state of UI, he obviously would require perfect ki control and he would have had to use SSJB to it's full extent to survive the spirit bomb.

Answer (score 1):

I think super saiyan blue mastered will come up if goku does like he did with ssj. If this is possible then goku could teach super blue to gohan or vegeta could teach it to future trunks [image]